# Siemens TIA portal, specifically tags

Tags: plc

I have a PLC with a profinet, connected to a profibus DP slave. The plc is connected to a HMI screen. I am very new to this software and the guide that came with it, doesnt help me with my problem. I have tags created for various I/O but I cannot link any of the tags to the slave, in the IO tags tab it just says, there are no IO tags to display. Does anybody know how to link the tags?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

Firstly very less information I get from your question, like what connection do you make betweeen PLC and HMI, Assuming you have profibus connection with AS-OS compile tags should be generated if connection is healthy. 
Then on HMI (assuming WinCC) go to Tag Management and the Simatic S7 Protocol Suite under this you will find connection Profibus, Right click and check System Parameter you will find logical device name. Make sure to select correct device name from the combo box.
Then it should be fixed.